# In VC++, is there any way to know the export class of a dll without any header files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, export

If there'are a few export class in a C++ Dll, but I don't have the Dll shared header files. So I don't know the definition of these export class, the only thing I know is the class name. Is there any way to find these export class and use them?

Now I can only use GetProcAddress API to find export functions, is there a similar API to find export classes?

I use VC++ 2008 compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is by reverse engineering (use a debugger) to find the required memory size before calling a constructor, and maybe you could figure out what members are used for (as well as inheritance and other goodies), but you will definitely not have correct names for anything other than exported functions. It might work, but it's a tough task.

Comment: Is there any symbol of the export class in the Dll? Can I use some API to get the export class address by symbol?

Comment: Probably not, and definitely not as a standard, required feature. It is possible to include such data in the dll resources, but that would be a very awkward method of sharing definition. Don't expect anything like this to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various tools 
1. http://www.dependencywalker.com 
2. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html
3. http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_syntax_lookup.htm

Comment: thanks, but I would like to use the export class in my program, not just view them.

Comment: How is this helpful? Will any of these tools expose the structure of a class? Will the members or required memory allocation be liseted?

Comment: OK so what you want is to reverse engineer a DLL , i had done that in past and it all depends upon how DLL is created so there is no single silver bullet for this, you can have a look at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/get-the-function-prototypes-from-an-unknown-dll

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to export functions from DLL.
1) Explicit linking to DLL
2) Implicit linking to DLL

1) If you want to use DLL which is created by using first approach
you will need

- .h file
- .DLL file
- .bin file

2) If you want to use DLL which is created by using second approach
you will need

- .DLL file only

In second case you need to 
- load DLL by yourself
- Calculate function address yourself -> GetProcAddress()
- Unload DLL yourself

If you have DLL,and don't know which classes or functions it is exporting
- use Dumpbin with /Exports options to know all exported functions.

Please let me know whether I clarified your dou